# How to use counter and flag in calculator android

Tags: android

I am developing calculator it is ok.just I have one issue with Counter
I used for equal bottom of this code:

```
int Counter =0;
Counter++;
if (Counter==1) {
    computeCalculation();
    edt2.setText(edt2.getText().toString() + decimalFormat.format(num2) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(num1));
    num1 = Double.NaN;
}
if (Counter>1){
    computeCalculation();
    edt2.setText( decimalFormat.format(num1) + decimalFormat.format(num2) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(num1));
}

}
```

but not worked.

how can add counter and flag for my project

```
        num1 = Double.NaN;
```

my num1 saved in counter1 NaN
and in counter 2 NaN+num2=NaN

please help me to num1 saved in counter 1
and use in counter 2

Comment: `but not worked for` what was the problem? how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: Probably a logical error . Try Debugging.

Comment: how can add counter and flag for my project

        num1 = Double.NaN;
my num1 saved in counter1 NaN and in counter 2 NaN+num2=NaN

please help me to num1 saved in counter 1 and use in counter 2

Comment: NaN + anything = NaN always

Comment: can you help me to solve this please

Comment: why are you storing NaN in counter?

Comment: if remove counter ...result NaN
please email to me 'tdanandeh@yahoo.com'to share code and please help me to solve

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, you have to write variables in camel case (**f.e.** myPrettyVarible).

**Second-moment**, if you write your calculator app I recommend you use some algorithms(**f.e.** Reverse Polish notation as well)

Comment: thank you , how can add counter and flag for my project

       ' num1 = Double.NaN;'
my num1 saved in counter1 NaN and in counter 2 NaN+num2=NaN

please help me to num1 saved in counter 1 and use in counter 2